# Div class display:none not working

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and so still finding my way a little...

I am trying to add a row of images at the bottom of my development [website](http://dev.sconchtextiles.co.uk)

This works fine for the desktop browser but I want to hide all but the Trustwave logo on mobile devices.

My theme is responsive and the following code works fine in jFiddle but not on my website.  Please could someone point out where I have missed something?

I know that I need to move the inline styling out to the CSS file but was first trying to find why display:none is not working properly.

HTML:

```
<div id="ft">
<div class="ftI">
    <div class="ftT">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('newsletter') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cms_footer_links') ?>
    </div>
    <div class="ftB">
        <span class="copr"><?php echo $this->getCopyright() ?></span>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_links') ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php /** ADD LOGOS TO FOOTER */ ?>
<div class="ftLogos" style="width:80%; height:56px; margin:0 auto;">
    <div class="ftFb" style="float:left; width:20%; text-align:center; margin:0 auto;"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>images/logos/footer-facebook.png" alt="Find us on FaceBook" /></div>
    <div class="ftTw" style="float:left; width:20%; text-align:center; margin:0 auto;"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>images/logos/footer-twitter.png" alt="Follow us on Twitter" /></div>
    <div class="ftSt" style="float:left; width:20%; text-align:center; margin:0 auto;"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>images/logos/footer-stripe.png" alt="Secure Card Payments by Stripe" /></div>
    <div class="ftPp" style="float:left; width:20%; text-align:center; margin:0 auto;"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>images/logos/footer-paypal.png" alt="Pay Securely by PayPal" /></div>
    <div class="ftTr" style="float:left; width:20%; text-align:center; margin:0 auto;"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://sealserver.trustwave.com/seal.js?style=normal"></script></div>
</div>
```

CSS (in the section for small screens only):

```
.ftFb {display:none;}
.ftTw {display:none;}
.ftSt {display:none;}
.ftPp {display:none;}
```

I'm happy to learn if there are better ways to format and ask questions on here :-)

Thanks,

Hugh

Comment: "I know that I need to move the inline styling out to the CSS" really? then please do so...

Comment: Works for me at http://dev.sconchtextiles.co.uk/

Comment: i'm using a 1366x768 display, and it really isn't a mobile.. i don't see any images @ the bottom other than the logo... am i missing something..?

Comment: It's possible your media query for the small screen isn't configured properly.

Comment: very strange - I can see all 5 logos on my desktop browser and all 5 logos on my mobile browser (including resizing my desktop browser to mobile size).  I have tried a totally new mobile browser to rule out any caching issues.  I want mobile users to only see the Trustwave logo (right hand one if you can see all 5 logos)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue looks to be you hiding it for all. You will need to remove it from media=all

```
media="all"
.ftTw {
 display: none; 
}
```

Looking through the css using chrome inspection. It looks like your media queries are doing the following. So for all except ftTr, they are hidden using the following code.

```
media="all"
@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
.ftPp {
display: none;
}
media="all"
.ftPp {
display: none;
}
```

The only icon i see is ftTr and its always shown. The rest are always hidden. I would suggest reviewing how your creating the media css.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  The 3 media queries I have are:

Desktop: '@include media-query($mq-l) {}'
Tablet: '@include media-query($mq-m) {}'
Mobile: no query

The image I wish to show is in .ftTr

Comment: Thank you - I cannot see that, I just see all 5 logos regardless of device or screen size, so I must have a local caching issue but it is strange that it is doing for me on all browsers/devices

Comment: Might want to check and make sure your not doing it by browser type as well. You could be doing it differently for ie, chrome, ff.

Comment: it's behaving identically for me in Firefox and Chrome as well as Android browsers and Chrome mobile on a smart phone.

Comment: I checked chrome, ie, android for you as well. Only the ftTr icon is shown and everything I checked. Most likely you have a cache issue.

Comment: I have just used a couple of online website testers that produce full page screen shots and they show all 5 icons for a browser size window so I am now completely confused as to what is actually happening on my website!